# À qui le traversait en début de phrase

Tags: ordre-des-mots

Bonjour,

*La vengeance du pardon* d'Éric-Emmanuel Schmitt :

> **À qui le traversait**, Saint-Sorlin-en-Bugey donnait le souvenir de
> n'avoir qu'une saison : le mois de mai.

Est-il possible de placer "À qui le traversait" en début de phrase dans une lettre ordinaire ou l'écrire dans un tchat, ou ce serait trop littéraire ?

Comment: La place importe peu à mon avis, c'est la tournure en elle-même qui est littéraire. Ensuite il n'y  aucune raison de ne pas adopter un style littéraire dans une lettre, une conversation, un tchat, etc. C'est une affaire de goût personnel, une question d'opinion et les avis sont sûrs de diverger à ce sujet.

Comment: Merci beaucoup @None :)

Answer (score 3):

« À qui » est ici employé sans antécédent, c'est une tournure qui est ressentie comme littéraire, en langage moins soutenu on dirait : « à celui qui/ aux personnes qui.. ».

> À ceux qui le traversaient Saint-Sorlin-en-Bugey donnait le souvenir de n'avoir qu'une saison : le mois de mai.

« À qui » est sujet de « traversait », et la proposition « À qui le traversait » est complément de « donnait ». Le fait de mettre le complément avant le verbe permet de mettre en relief ce complément mais ce n'est pas spécialement littéraire. En lisant [le paragraphe](https://books.google.fr/books?id=C7stDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT3&lpg=PT3&dq=%22%C3%80%20qui%20le%20traversait,%20Saint-Sorlin-en-Bugey%20donnait%20le%20souvenir%20de%20n%27avoir%20qu%27une%20saison%20:%20le%20mois%20de%20mai.%22&source=bl&ots=JobjvSdXkp&sig=ACfU3U28JSX2C_hLdnRIBGP6WNMVuF9ZMg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9g_bEgO70AhXJzIUKHbCZBFQQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%80%20qui%20le%20traversait%2C%20Saint-Sorlin-en-Bugey%20donnait%20le%20souvenir%20de%20n%27avoir%20qu%27une%20saison%20%3A%20le%20mois%20de%20mai.%22&f=false) où se trouve cette phrase on voit que l'auteur utilise beaucoup ce procédé d'inversion. Mettre en avant un complément relève d'un procédé stylistique mais ce n'est pas forcément littéraire.

Par ailleurs je ne vois pas ce qui empêcherait d'utiliser des tournures littéraires ou des procédés stylistiques particuliers dans une lettre ou un tchat. C'est une question de contexte, et ça dépend aussi de l'impression que l'on veut créer.

Answer (score -1):

La suite normale de phrase est: Sujet > verbe >> objet. Exemple: Décor: Il y a sur la table plusieurs fruits à manger..... ''Je mangerai la pomme''. Maintenant, pour mettre en évidence l'importance que j'attache à cette déposition, je formule en conséquence comme suit: ''La pomme ----virgule---- je la mangerai en premier.'' // Donc, en l'occurrence : Celui qui ne traverse, ne connaît pas cet endroit nommé St-Sorlin-en-Bugey n'aura pas le souvenir d'un endroit où il n'est qu'une seule saison, celle du mois de mai. Donc, il faut mettre l'élément important en début de phrase, suivi impérativement d'une virgule, donc ''la personne qui traverse cette région, cette localité'', car seulement celle-là se rendra compte de ce fait naturel d'unique saison ....de mai. Le cas est donc clair, c'est une question de stylistique recherchée. Eh bien, c'est cela de la belle littérature, la recherche du vocabulaire exquis et de la formulation plaisante du contenu pas courante.